# Custom SSL cert not working in Bluemix

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud

We purchased a certificate from GoDaddy and I have uploaded the public, private and intermediate keys into the domain management dialog. When I view the cert it says "unknown" and still serves the *.mybluemix.net cert.

I used openssl to convert the crt and key into a p12 to verify they match and the -modulus/md5 checks match.

is there something on the Bluemix side I have to do, or does it just take 24 hrs to work?

Comment: Did you configure DNS for your domain? Check this block for detailed instructions - http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/bluemix-ui-ssl-certificates-and-custom.html

Comment: We had it working but with a "CNAME"  so now I will change it to a "A" record and test again

Comment: Yes that worked, changing from a "CNAME" to "A" was the answer.

Answer (score 3):

By changing our DNS from "CNAME" to "A" the Bluemix server gave us the correct cert.